# Strange effects in streaming with Facebook live

Tags: streaming

I'm streaming some songs with a video in Facebook live using OBS Studio and VLC player. In some particular songs, I get the strange effect that the video speeds up. I could understand that the video slows down, but speed up? That doesnt make any sense to me. Is this some issue related to the streaming or configuration of Facebook live streaming service?